# Usage data from log file

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, http

Is there any way I can tell from the apache log files how many users are using an application and how often the use it?  I kind of want the information that you would normally get from google analytics, but these sites do not have google analytics.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, try a web-log analyzer, here's [a list to start with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_analytics_software)

Comment: I found this one its great ! https://www.sawmill.net/